# Slow Looper in Android Studio due to Async Task

Tags: java, android

Well I want to display some countries on the console but it is not working. See my code below:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < covidCountryList.size(); i++) {
            String domain = covidCountryList.get(i).getIso2();
            GETCountries getCountries = new GETCountries(domain);
            getCountries.execute();
            System.out.println(countryList.get(i).getName());
        }
```

As you can see I want to print the `i` element on the console but it is not showing anything. No exception and not the text I want. I found a Warning on the console which says this

```
W/Looper: Slow Looper main: Activity mypackage/.MainActivity is 323ms late (wall=8ms running=0ms ClientTransaction{ lifecycleRequest=android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem }) because of 6 msg, msg 1 took 533ms (seq=3 late=204ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159)
```

Comment: try adding Log.d(...)

Comment: Also not working